# Java: do-while(regex), hashtable.containsKey() possible?

Tags: java, regex, hashtable, do-while

Can I use a Regular Expression with Hashtable.containsKey(Object value);

Is there any way to do the following pseudo-code?

```
while ( myHashtable.containsKey(regex) ) {
    //TODO
};
```

Where my regex would be "ERROR[0-9][0-9]?"

edit: I'm setting any number of error messages from a backend Java program which gets sent to the JSP as a hashtable. The JSP needs to display these error messages from the hashtable. Using the hashtable in the JSP is non-negotiable. I just need to know how to make sure we read all of the error messages.

Comment: If you want you can edit your post and write what you want to achieve, so that we may propose alternative solutions to the problem.

Comment: not possible; hashing is done on "exact match"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the way you're suggesting.

Hash tables use an `Object`'s `hashCode` and `equals` methods to quickly find the object you are looking for.

Instead you can iterate through the hash table's elements and look for matches like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : myHashtable.entrySet){
    if (regex.matcher(entry.getKey()).matches()) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested any of this but since the function you want to use expects an Object and you want to use a regular expression, you need an object that is a regular expression.

You could give the object Pattern a shot: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html